# calculating norm of the following matrix?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I have the following matrix and its norm
$$ \begin{aligned} A(s) &= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & e^{-sT} \\ e^{-sT}   & 0 \end{bmatrix}  \\
\lvert \lvert {A(s)} \rvert \rvert_{\infty} &= \sup_{w} \sqrt{\lambda_{\max} (A^{*}(jw)A(jw)) } = 1 \end{aligned}$$

I want to know how the norm has been acquired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Then 
$\hat{A}(s) = e^{-sT} H$, hence
$\|\hat{A}(s)\| = |e^{-sT}| \| H \|$.

$\| H\| = \sqrt{\|H^*H\|}= \sqrt{\|H^*H\|}=\sqrt{\|I\|} = 1$.

Hence $\|\hat{A}(s)\| = |e^{-sT}|$.

Now, the $H_\infty$ norm is given by $\|\hat{A}\|_\infty = \sup_\omega \|A(j \omega)\|$, and $\|\hat{A}(j \omega)\| =1$ for all $\omega$, hence the desired result.

Comment: Forgive me for this question, you didn't use $\lambda$ why? And I would like to know to calculate $ A^{*}(jw)A(jw) $ to allow me to the find the max eigenvalue

Comment: $\|A^*A\| = \lambda_\max (A^*A)$.

Comment: thanks for being helpful and informative. last question is how to calculate $A^{*}(jw)A(jw)$?

Comment: $A(j \omega)$ is just a (complex) matrix, so $A(j \omega)^*A(j \omega)$ is just the product of the conjugate transpose (adjoint) with the matrix itself.

Comment: As an aside, $A$ is the transfer function of a pure delay that swaps channels, so you would expect the gain to be 1. The norm loses phase information, of course.

Comment: You are welcome!